# Set display refresh rate of Qt application

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any easy way of setting the LCD refresh rate of a QT application?
Since my application is almost static, I would like to decrease the refresh rate to 30 fps.

This is the `main.cpp` code:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: On which platform are you? I can imagine that this has to be done in a platform specific way.

Comment: So you want to change the monitor settings? What would be the advantage of changing the refresh rate to 30 fps (as opposed to the default of 60)?

Comment: Decreasing CPU-load for instance.

Comment: @KimKulling: I'd never used Qml. Are you sure it renders everything continuously even if nothing changes?

Comment: Yes, we measured it here and the underlying scenegraph will render a static image with 60 FPS if this is the upper vsync-limit,

Comment: @KimKulling: sounds that you are better to either optimize the scene-graph or change to another technology.

Comment: Why consuming CPU-power without any needs? When decreasing cpu-load you are also decreasing power consumption, which means increasing time working with your battery etc. special on some embedded devices :-). And unfortunately sometimes changing technology is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to decrease the refresh rate via VSync-setting. Unfortunately this setting will touch the whole device, so this solution works best for embedded devices with only your application running.
Changing Vsync-rate is normally os-dependent. So if you are planning to do it just check how to do this for your OS.